# Magento: placing available blocks

Tags: cms, magento, page

I've installed a custom theme in Magendo. I browse pages and get shocked. Some pages have blocks, other - no, some have the left sidebar, some - the right. The complete mess.

How can I know all the blocks that are available in my customized/not customized Magento store and theme? I don't know what my Magento has.
I've found Shop By, Select Currency, Tags, Compare, Recent, Cart, Poll blocks visiting pages. How can I get the full list? Cause there could be other blocks that I haven't seen.

How can I place those blocks on the left side on pages I want? How to enable/disable blocks?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: There is a Magento Stack Exchange you might want to get involved in, http://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

you need to dig in the xml files to change the blocks, unless you're in Magento Go which has a block editor in the design tab